# magento 1.7 - adding dynamic content to home page

Tags: magento, block

I would like to add dynamic content to front page of Magento site that looks like this...

[image]

I wrote a small "template program" called myPgm.phtml that looks like this:

```
<?php
$cats = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load(2)->getChildren();
$catIds = explode(',' , $cats);
?>
<div class='block block-list'> 
    <div class='block-title'><strong><span>Goto Category</span></strong></div>
        <div class='block-content'> 
            <ul>
            <?php foreach($catIds as $catId): ?>
                <ul>
                    <?php
                        $category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($catId);
                        echo '<li>&nbsp; <a href="' . $category->getUrl() . '">';
                        echo $category->getName() . '</a></li>';
                    ?>
                </li>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
            </ul>
         </div>

</div>
```

I put this in:
app/design/frontend/default/mytheme/template/catalog/navigation/mypgm.phtml

Then in the front page CMS->Pages->Design, I added the following XML reference in side the "&gtreference name="header"&lt" section.

```
 <block type="core/template" name="catalog.category" template="catalog/navigation/mypgm.phtml">
 </block>
```

I put it next to an existing block that does appear on front page.
However my new block does not appear. What am I missing?

---

---

---

I did some additional testing.  It works when I put it CMS->Pages->Front-Page->Content as
{{block type="core/template" name="catalog.category" template="catalog/navigation/mypgm.phtml"}}

I also works when I drop the block in this form:

```
<block type="catalog/navigation" name="catalog.category" template ="catalog/navigation/category.phtml"/>
```

... in content, left, and right "reference" sections, however not in header... maybe program has not fully boostrapped when header is created????

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this on your CMS page:

`{{block type="core/template" name="giveitaname" template="path/to/your.phtml"}}`

Comment: yes intesresting... it works as expected in this context, however it drops it in the center middle of the page, which is not where client wants it :(

Comment: Can it be moved using CSS? I am not completely certain what it did incorrectly.

Comment: Grr, I hate using css to backfill for bad code... I did additional tests and documented above.  Maybe someone else has had this problem?